# JPA Lazy Load on non abstract objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets, jpa

I am trying to 'tune' my application, and maybe speed it up a little bit. I'm using hibernate as my JPA implementation, and I have an entity called Product. It consists of a name, description, id, and an image, represented as a byte[] in the class definition.

On the 'web tier side', I have a servlet(ProductServlet) whose GET method goes out and retrieves a List of all Product objects from the database, puts them in the request as an attribute, and forwards off to a JSP, where the products are displayed in a table.

In order to display the images, (based on some advice I found on displaying byte[] data as an image in a JSP) I have a separate servlet(ImageServlet) whose GET method returns a JPG encoded image of the product whose ID is passed in.

My question is, is there a way I can have the image(byte[]) be 'lazy loaded', so that when I make the initial request to my ProductServlet, the List of products returned do not have the image(byte[]) attribute retrieved until I explicitly call product.getImage() (I'm assuming that's how lazy load works).

That way, the initial call to the backend database to get the List of products is quicker, since all the byte[] data is not returned, and then when I only get the byte[] image portion when I need to get the images(using the ImageServlet).

I tried to set the lazy fetch attribute on my byte[] image attribute, but it said that was not allowed, I'm guessing because it's a standard Java class, and not an abstract class that I defined myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPA 2 you mark column as `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`. If JPA 1 you can create a `SimpleProduct` entity that will consist only basic information without the image. However mind that even if your db does not return a column value (it's not in the select clause) it's being read from the disk. This costs.

Rather than that I'll leave the first step as is. After all products are loaded I'd put images into the cache (you can use simple [Guava cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)) and the `ImageServlet` should read from the cache. Make it a short-life cache (like 15 seconds) and provide a loader that in case that the image is not in the cache somehow, then hit the database.

Comment: I'll accept your answer shortly, I guess I have to wait a few minutes. Thanks for the advice, I'll look into the Guava cache. I like that solution. I wish there was an easy way to display the image from the JSP since I already have the byte[], as opposed to having to use a separate servlet.

Comment: You can try with Base64 images put into HTML byt IT'S WRONG WAY! It's better to load images on separate HTTP calls since HTML rendering will be faster and GETs for images will be loaded faster.